# On-Device debugging + Net Beans + Android

Tags: android

How can i do On-Device(Sony Ericcson XPERIA) debudding by using Net Beans ?

Thanks and Regards...

Answer (score 1):

There is a debugging help area in the Android sdk doc : http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

It talk abot debugging and running on real device. Hope it help.

For netbeans there is an android device called nbandroid there is a version out for the version 7 of netbeans.